# .htaccess Rewrite Wordpress Subdirectory without breaking other subdirectories

Tags: htaccess, wordpress, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

So I have WordPress installed in `/wp/` but I want all WordPress URLs to be rewritten to appear in the root directory. I currently have this working (see below) but I want to change my `.htaccess` so it doesn't break other subdirectories.

For example, if I want to visit `www.example.com/images/image.png`, it currently reroutes me to a 404 page on WordPress.

Is this even possible with `.htaccess`?

Current code:

```
RewriteEngine on

#Wordpress
# Rewrites all URLS without wp in them
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/wp/

# Rewrites all URLS [Replace "example" with the actual domain, without the TLD (.com, .net, .biz, etc)]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?example\.

# Rewrite all those to insert /folder
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /wp/$1 [L]
```

**Update**: Tested MrWhite's suggestion with Incognito mode and a second browser.  No effect.  New `.htaccess` file:

```
RewriteEngine on

#Wordpress
# Rewrites all URLS without wp in them
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/wp/

# Rewrites all URLS [Replace "example" with the actual domain, without the TLD (.com, .net, .biz, etc)]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?example\.

# Rewrite all those to insert /folder
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /wp/$1 [L]
# Request does not map to an existing file
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to add a condition to exclude existing files, otherwise a request for `/images/image.png` will naturally be rewritten to `/wp/images/image.png` and trigger a 404 in WordPress (unless `/wp/images/image.png` did actually exist).

For example, add the following condition to your existing rule:

```
# Request does not map to an existing file
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
```

---

> **UPDATE:** this did not seem to work. Still goes to the WordPress 404 page

You've put the `RewriteCond` directive in the wrong place.

`RewriteCond` directives are not entirely separate statements, they are *conditions* that apply to the `RewriteRule` directive that follows. By themselves, `RewriteCond` directives don't do anything.

The `RewriteCond` directive needs to go (anywhere) *before* the `RewriteRule` directive:

```
RewriteEngine on

#Wordpress
# Rewrites all URLS without wp in them
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/wp/

# Rewrites all URLS [Replace "example" with the actual domain, without the TLD (.com, .net, .biz, etc)]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?example\.

# Request does not map to an existing file
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f

# Rewrite all those to insert /folder
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /wp/$1 [L]
```

Also, have a look at the "WordPress" `.htaccess` file in the `/wp` subdirectory for reference. That does the same sort of thing.

*Aside:* Unless you have multiple domains or subdomains that you don't want rewritten then you can remove the hostname check (ie. the `RewriteCond` directive that checks against the `HTTP_HOST` server variable).

Comment: Unfortunately, this did not seem to work.  Still goes to the WordPress 404 page.

Comment: Please post the updated contents of your `.htaccess` file in your question, Make sure you've cleared your browser cache.

Comment: I have added the modified `.htaccess`code to the question.  Tested it with Incognito mode.

Comment: You've put the `RewriteCond` directive in the wrong place. I've updated my answer.

Comment: Ahh, thank you for the explanation.  This worked.  Thanks so much.